# play 3gp videos on windows mobile 5 and 6 from code?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, pocketpc, windows-mobile-6

currently im able to play .wmv videos from my application using shell execute which plays it in the windowsmedia player. However I need to be able to play .3gp videos which unfortunately the windows meadia player does not support. Is it possible via api etc to play 3gp videos on win mobile 5 and 6 devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [CorePlayer](http://coreplayer.com/), though you need to purchase a license. I am not familiar with a free solution to play this media unless the device's OEM provides it.